# LinkedIn API network-stats says 'access to network denied' although i've granted r_network

Tags: php, linkedin-api, lithium

Im working on a php project and using simple REST requests...  I've successfully authenticated using the r_fullprofile, r_emailaddress and r_network scopes...  I'm trying to get my network stats using GET '/v1/people/~/network/network-stats' however, instead of getting results, i'm getting the following response:

```
object(stdClass)[45]
  public 'errorCode' => int 0
  public 'message' => string 'Access to network denied' (length=24)
  public 'requestId' => string '6XO26HIVWA' (length=10)
  public 'status' => int 403
  public 'timestamp' => int 1417925091035
```

I've granted my app r_network, so why am I not seeing values?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *r_network* use *rw_nus* , It worked for me. rw_nus allows you to get the NETWORK UPDATES.

Answer (score 0):

REST API endpoints are no longer be available for general use.

The rw_nus member permission deprecated.

https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition